# Create a SQL Trigger to alter multiple rows into another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using databases to connect with PowerApps and PowerBI and I had a question about triggers.

I have a table (Table A) that contains three columns: ID, TotalQty & Date. I would like to create a trigger based on the three main row actions: Insert, Delete & Update.

Example: New row is inserted into Table A from PowerApps (ID = 1000000 & TotalQty = 3 & Date = Today)

This should fire the trigger three times to insert a row into Table B (with rows ID, QrderQty, and Date):

1. ID = 1000000, OrderQty = 1 of 3, Date = Today
2. ID = 1000000, OrderQty = 2 of 3, Date = Today
3. ID = 1000000, OrderQty = 3 of 3, Date = Today

Similarly, if the date column is updated on Table A for this row, I need the three corresponding rows to update their respective date values as well. Or if the row in Table A is deleted, I need the three rows to be removed.

Could anybody give me an example query of this?

Comment: As you have said you are a newbie in SQL Server then you should first learn the basics of the trigger and the case statement on a temp table rather than on an actual table. Here is the trigger reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 and case statement reference is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Trigger first this [link](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-create-trigger/) contains some tutorial on how to create a trigger.

Then according to your question you need to do some kind of loop for generating values for the OrderQty, I have done  a `while loop` in this answer that exists as part of `TSQL`

Assuming that you create `TableA` and `TableB` with following schemas:

```
create table [dbo].[TableA]
(
ID integer not null,
TotalQty integer not null,
Date Date not null
)
go
create table [dbo].[TableB]
(
ID integer not null,
OrderQty nvarchar(10) not null,
Date Date not null
)
go
```

You can create the trigger as follows to do the job for you:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertFromAToB]
ON [dbo].[TableA]
AFTER  INSERT
AS
BEGIN
Declare @counter as integer;
set @counter=1;
Declare @qty as integer;
set @qty = (Select TotalQty from inserted);
    While(@counter <= @qty)
    Begin
        Insert into TableB(ID,OrderQty,Date) select ID,(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@counter) + ' of ' + Convert(nvarchar(10),@qty)) as OrderQty,Date From inserted
        set @counter=@counter+1;
    END
END
```